# Icefaces fileEntry - need to process the file after rendering the response

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am uploading excel file using ace:fileEntry. I want the file to be parsed into an array of objects using POI. How do I render the response from FileEntryListener and pass the control to another java class without the user waiting for the whole file to be processed?

Thanks and Regards,
Jay

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to get a useful answers, it's best to provide us with something to go on. Please refer to the guidelines in http://sscce.org

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Using `ace:fileEntry` you can upload a file to a specific directory and I think this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) gives a very good method of implementation which would suit your needs. You just need to fire some events based on file creation in a pool of threads.